# Laravel 5.6 opening a form with laravel collective for named route with id

Tags: php, laravel

my route:

```
$this->post('imagerequests/{id}/save-building', 'ImageRequestController@saveBuildingImage')->name('saveBuildingImage');
```

my opening form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => ['saveBuildingImage' => $imageRequest->id])) }}
```

When I `dd($imageRequest)` I see the id in the attributes so no problem there.

error message:

> Undefined offset: 0 in FormBuilder.php line 1160

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's route expects the `$id` variable. But in the view, you didn't send **variable name**. Without using *Laravel collective* package notation you should use in this form to pass data:

```
route('saveBuildingImage', ['id' => $imageRequest->id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue to fix it using Laravel Collective

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('saveBuildingImage', $imageRequest->id))) }}
```

Comment: Didn't work this? :
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('saveBuildingImage', ['id' => $imageRequest->id]))) }}

Comment: @MahdiJedari I didn't try it sorry, fixed it before I saw your solution.

Comment: That's nice. Was the problem caused by array notation?

Comment: @MahdiJedari yeah probably by mixing different notations or something like that